# Abstraction layer between iphone and database

Tags: iphone, python, abstraction

I've built a backend in python that posts data to the database.  I want a layer of abstraction, so I thought that the best thing to do was to call a python function from objective-c.  The python function would then post to the database.  How can this be done?

Comment: I presume this is a remote database on a web server somewhere?

Comment: yes, exactly. Any way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access the Python function via a web server (potentially using an intermediate scripting language to call the Python script). You can read more about this via http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html

Being honest, it may prove to be less hassle to simply use a more common web scripting language (i.e.: not Python) if this is an option.

Moving on, in terms of the iPhone-side activity, you'll need to :

1. Ensure there's a network connection available to the remote site in question. (There's a plethora of questions here on Stack Overflow, such as: [Determining Internet Availability on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741145/determining-internet-availability-on-iphone))
2. Open a request to the remote web server.
   The [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class should be ideal for this.
3. Handle the results of the above correctly.