# how to SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName with macruby

Tags: pointers, macruby

i really don't know how to convert the example provided by apple into macruby code, since address is a char pointer, irghhh:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityRef target;
SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags = 0;
Boolean ok;

target = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, address);
ok = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(target, &flags);

CFRelease(target);
```

here is an example implementation in Objective-C:

[Determining Internet Availability on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741145/determining-internet-availability-on-iphone/741530#741530)

UPDATE:

i just realized, that i can do it very quickly with macruby itself, but i am stil interested in how you would do this with macruby.

```
def network_available?
  Socket.getaddrinfo('example.com', nil)
rescue
  false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply get the pointer of your MacRuby NSString instance:

```
address = "example.com".pointer
...
target = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, address)
```